# httpd-xampp.conf: Allow Access to an external system using Host Name instead of IP Address?

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

A server is deployed to be used on internal network, where I can access `PHPmyAdmin` using localhost or from  having static IP.

I want to access page on my notebook which does not have static IP, but has `NSM` as `hostname`.

Currently, the following code is configured in `httpd-xampp.conf`. I tried to use Host name in place of the IP address but MySQL returns error.

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "D:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        Require ip <private-ip>
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Require host` in `httpd-xampp.conf` (with Apache 2.4.25)

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    Require host host_name.domain_name
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```